# Plasma doesn't remember window positions in dual screen einvironment

Tags: 20.04, plasma

I'm using Plasma desktop 5.24 with a laptop that has a small screen and an external display.

When the external display is switched off, all the windows move to the laptop display (at the left).
When I switch it on again, I have to manually move all the windows back to the big display.

Comment: Have you tried shutting down the laptop before the external display?

Comment: Itt wourld work if I suspend or hibernate the computer before switching off the display

Comment: How it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If I connect by VGA, then the computer doesn't realize a monitor is switched off, so this problem disappears.

With HDMI, I do have this problem.

So the solution in my case is to use VGA.